# How to specify status code in Google Cloud Function response?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I created a function that transforms some data and sends it to FB API.
It works perfectly when FB API responds with 200 code, otherwise function returns internal server error.

I've added `raise_for_status()` and now I can return an error message if FB API responds with non-200 code.
How can I make my function not only to respond with a relevant error message but with the relevant status code?[image]

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, params=params)
resp = {}

try:
    response.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    response.status_code = 400
    resp['message'] = response.text
else:
    resp['message'] = response.text
finally:
    return resp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the HTTP code after your response, like this

```
return resp, 403
```