# Best way to raise an exception and simultaneously return a HTTP error code in a Python Cloud Function

Tags: python-3.x, http, exception, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am having some trouble combining two requirements that were communicated to me.

The initial requirement I had was to handle exceptions in the GCP Cloud Function I had created to insert JSON data into BigQuery. The basic logic was as follows:

```
import json
import google.auth
from google.cloud import bigquery

class SomeRandomException(Exception):
    """Text explaining the purpose of this exception"""

def main(request):
    """Triggered by another HTTP request"""

    # Instantiation of BQ client
    credentials, your_project_id = google.auth.default(
        scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    )
    client = bigquery.Client(credentials=credentials, project=your_project_id, )

    # JSON reading
    json_data: dict = request.get_json()

    final_message: str = ""
    table_name = "someTableName"

    for row in json_data:
        rows_to_insert: list = []                    
        rows_to_insert.append(row["data"])

        if rows_to_insert:
            errors: list = client.insert_rows_json(
                table_name, rows_to_insert, row_ids=[None] * len(rows_to_insert)
            )
            if errors == []:
                final_message = f"\n{len(rows_to_insert)} row(s) successfully inserted in table\n"
            else:
                raise SomeRandomException(
                    f"Encountered errors while inserting rows into table: {errors}"
                )

    return final_message
```

(please note that there are other exceptions being handled in the code but I tried to simplify the above logic to make things easier to analyze)

Then I received a second requirement saying that, in addition to raising an exception, I had to return a HTTP error code. I discovered in another StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65681011/how-to-specify-status-code-in-google-cloud-function-response) that it was easy to return an error code along with some message. But I haven't found anything that clearly explains how to return that error code and, at the same time, raise an exception. From what I know, *raise* and *return* are mutually exclusive statements. So, is there any solution to gracefully combine the exception handling and the HTTP error?

Would the below snippet for instance be acceptable or is there a better way? I'm really confused because an exception is supposed to use a *raise* whereas a HTTP code needs a *return*.

```
else:
    return SomeRandomException(
        f"Encountered errors while inserting rows into table: {errors}"
    ), 500
```

Comment: Your code can throw an exception anywhere you want. Someplace you need to catch the exception and then return the error status you want. Otherwise, a default handler will execute, and usually, the default handler terminates your program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building on John's comment. You want to raise the exception in the code you have and then add a try-except to catch/handle the exception and return the error.

```py
class SomeRandomException(Exception):
    # add custom attributes if need be
    pass


try: 
    # your code ...
    else:
        raise SomeRandomException("Custom Error Message!")
except SomeRandomException as err:
    # caught exception, time to return error
    response = {
        "error": err.__class__.__name__,
        "message": "Random Exception occured!"
    }
    # if exception has custom error message
    if len(err.args) > 0:
        response["message"] = err.args[0]
    return response, 500
```

To go one step further you could also integrate [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries) with the Python root logger so that right before returning the error you also log the error to Cloud Function's logs like so:
`logging.error(err)`

This would just help make the logs easier to query later on.